# Built iOS Application Using Expo For React Native. App Icon Is Missing After Uploading to Apple Connect

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm hoping that I am missing something simple here. I built a mobile application for iOS using the `expo build:ios` command and successfully downloaded the ipa file. I transported the file from my Windows machine to my Mac and uploaded it to Apple Connect using the Transporter application. The app runs perfectly fine in TestFlight but the app icon is missing. When I built the same app for Android, no such problem occurred. I will include my `app.json` document below. I replaced the app name with 'xxxxx' so that should be ignored. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "xxxxx",
    "slug": "xxxxx",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.13",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/img/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "xxxxx"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "xxxxx",
      "versionCode": 4,
      "permissions": ["NOTIFICATIONS"]
    }
  }
} I
```

Comment: Does `YourProject/ios/YourProject/images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` have your app icons ?

Comment: I don't believe my project has appiconset. It's built in React Native. Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming your app is created using `expo init`, Do you have `icon.png` under the `assets` folder?  Also [android you might need to have an adaptive icon](https://docs.expo.io/guides/app-icons/#android)

Comment: Yes, I have an icon in the assets folder. The app is actually already in the Google Play store and the icon looks fine.